# How to mount a Vue instance to a not yet appended HTML element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

In an app I'm creating I want to mount a `Vue` instance to an `HTML Node`. But after using the `$mount` function, the `Node` doesn't contain the `Vue` instance.

In the code below you can see what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to return an `HTML Node` containing the `Vue` instance.

```
const el = document.createElement('div');
new Vue({
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(HelloWorldVue, {}, {});
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorldVue,
  },
}).$mount(el);
return el;
```

Does anybody have an idea how to mount the Vue instance to the generated element before mounting it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el):

> Unlike in Vue 1.x, the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases.

So this will not work. But you can do something similar by calling `$mount()` without [any argument](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount):

> If `elementOrSelector` argument is not provided, the template will be rendered as an off-document element, and you will have to use native DOM API to insert it into the document yourself.

```js
// or, render off-document and append afterwards:
var component = new MyComponent().$mount()
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(component.$el)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the final piece of the puzzle :)

Comment: It is not possible to use something similar inVUE3. It seems that mounting in off document way is not possible any more.